# How to delete a queue in Rabbitmq programmatically in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

In my node server, I used amqplib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) to interact with the local Rabbitmq server. I created a queue using the library in Rabbitmq. Is there any way to delete the queue? I couldn't find any solution in the amqplib docs I am not sure if there is one...Can I do it using amqplib or is there any other way in node js to create and delete queue in Rabbitmq?

Comment: as per my knowledge , once you subscribe/listen to the queue , it will be automatically deleted or removed from the queue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two way:

- create queue with `autoDelete=true` option, the queue will be deleted when no consumers
- [channel.deleteQueue()](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_deleteQueue) manually